# Recreate TFS 2010 build sequence in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, build-process, tfsbuild

in the build workflow for TFS 2010 I could drill down into Compile and Test, locate the Foreach Project loop and get the workflow variable assignment of BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild (serverBuildProjectItem).

Is there alternative to this in the new streamlined build workflow for TFS 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProjectsToBuild is available as a workflow Argument.

A lot of things that used to be Workflow Variables (e.g. SourcesDirectory, BinariesDirectory, etc) have been moved to Environment Variables that you use the GetEnvironmentVariable activity to get their values.  For the list of Environment Variables available that are set by TFS see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.activities.extensions.wellknownenvironmentvariables.aspx

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Dylan! I also used to be able to get the build agent id with the following syntax: 
`LinkingUtilities.DecodeUri(BuildAgent.Uri.AbsoluteUri).ToolSpecificId`

Is there an equivalent in 2013 as well?

Comment: I edited my answer to link to the MSDN page that lists the environment variables.  One of them is BuildAgent which I think will give you what you want.